# What do we actually study in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I just started learning machine learning and learned a few basic algorithms and there is one stupid doubt in my mind and I am unable to find the answer of it.
What do we actually study in machine learning algorithms that solves kinds of problems based on the data given to the algorithms?

Take an example of linear regression:

1. We give data.
2. We tell machine how to calculate error.
3. Using gradient descent also we are telling machine how to optimize 
   and based on all above some optimized parameters come out .

Why there is actually a "learning" word in this algorithm? Although we are the  telling how to perform steps and we have provided all the mathematics in this algorithm.

Comment: This question would certainly be better welcomed on the Data Science part of Stack Exchange. You are more likely to get good answers there :  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are considering as learning is not learning at all. It is designing the model. Where learning means updating the parameters based on the data. As I am thinking now you are not very much clear about the reasons why we even use machine learning. Machine learning is used for the problems where the problems **cannot be explicitly programmed or it is difficult to write a programs on them explicitly.**

Let's say you want to make a classifier that can differentiate between cat vs dog. So what if you were told to program it manually?-I.e, making rules by yourself that can be used to differentiate a cat from a dog? Can you just imagine how much painful it would be to find these rules manually?-E.g, cats have mustache but dogs don't have....And sometimes it may not be possible to do it by yourself at all if the target classes are very much abstract or there are lots of features to be considered.

Again machine learning is quite **general purpose.** Once you have made an appropriate model it can be trained on anything relevant. It just wants from you numerical data and appropriate output labels (supervised learning). So the same cat vs dog model can be used for duck vs chicken, if you train it for that. Here you need not know the differences on appearance between a cat and a dog or a chicken and a hen. Again you need not find these differences manually and write code on them manually. The model is itself learning the differences from data. All you need to do just to pre-process the data (converting to appropriate numerical data which a ML model can take).

Linear regression is a very preliminary type of ML algorithm. If you learn more advanced ML algorithms like- Neural Network, SVM, Random Forest etc then the reasons will be clearer to you.